# Reference to the slidingViewController from the AppDelegate to open a view

Tags: appdelegate, ecslidingviewcontroller

I need to open a view as topViewController from the AppDelegate method :

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:             
(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

but I don't know how to make the reference to the slidingViewController....